# WPF XAML - Creating a Button with Border, Path and text overlaying each other, all styles controlled by the Button

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to create a `Button` that has a `Border` (rounded corners), which has a `Path` vector overlaying it and the `Path` has some text from `Label` on top of it.

I've created triggers that when you hover over this Button the style of all these nested elements change.

**The Problem**
I'm not sure where to place the Label text as I still need access to it from the code behind to get and set it text value, but I also need to trigger or bind its color to the Borders color which I can't access from inside the `Template` or outside to make this all work.

Maybe I need to use a different layout structure? Although most of it is working fine so far except the `Label`

**Code inside xaml file**

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Width="70" Height="70" Background="#FF474747">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="#FF272727">
                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="pth"  Opacity="1" Fill="#FF515151" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="m 18.16782 0 -7.64541 5.81323 0 61.04669 L 0 66.85992 0 70 l 61.43133 0 0 -3.14008 -20.17455 0 0 -55.87557 L 18.16782 0 Z m -4.15996 15.70413 23.54902 0 0 1.69254 -20.74683 1.78854 0 15.00717 20.74683 1.78792 0 1.69254 -23.54902 0 0 -21.96871 z m 11.2761 5.08198 a 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 5.79266 5.79266 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 -5.79266 5.79328 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 -5.79328 -5.79328 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 5.79328 -5.79266 z" FillRule="evenodd"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FFDE2029"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="pth" Property="Fill" Value="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FFFF445D"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

    <Label x:Name="lblText" Content="Ab" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial"  Foreground="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=btn}" FontSize="22" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the label be in the Button.Template?

Comment: Where do I place it exactly, because I seem to getting errors wherever I place it, like `The Property 'Visual Tree' is set more than once`, `Propery Templete can only be set once` and `Template does not support values of type 'Label' etc...

Comment: <Border><Grid><Path><Label> or <Border><Grid><Label><Path>  Grid, StackPanel and DockPanel can hold as many items as you want

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that I needed a container. Same as the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Grid and put both Lable and Path in it and change the Binding:

```
 <Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Name="window"
    xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Tag="ABC" Width="70" Height="70" Background="#FF474747">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="#FF272727">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="pth"  Opacity="1" Fill="#FF515151" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry Figures="m 18.16782 0 -7.64541 5.81323 0 61.04669 L 0 66.85992 0 70 l 61.43133 0 0 -3.14008 -20.17455 0 0 -55.87557 L 18.16782 0 Z m -4.15996 15.70413 23.54902 0 0 1.69254 -20.74683 1.78854 0 15.00717 20.74683 1.78792 0 1.69254 -23.54902 0 0 -21.96871 z m 11.2761 5.08198 a 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 5.79266 5.79266 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 -5.79266 5.79328 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 -5.79328 -5.79328 5.793155 5.793155 0 0 1 5.79328 -5.79266 z" FillRule="evenodd"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Label x:Name="lblText" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Arial"  
                               Content="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                               Foreground="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}" FontSize="22" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FFDE2029"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="pth" Property="Fill" Value="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FFFF445D"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</Window>

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
        Tag = "ABC";
}
```

Note that you can bind the Content Property in a similar pattern.

Comment: I'm new to wpf and xaml, so I'm not sure how you would do that? Would I still create a control template that would target the `Grid`, so that I can set the styles and triggers from there?

Comment: I posted the whole Xaml. Note that Label.Content is bound to the Tag Propety of your MainWindow. You can define Custom properties. You can Set DataContext too.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. Also you should change the Labels Content binding to AncestorType=Button in your example above, you must have accidentally added Border causing it the Tag not to work.